# Тире или запятые в сложном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, спп

Цитата: *Специально для вас - чтобы слегка разбавить текст - лучшая подборка из передачи.*

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно расставить в этом предложении знаки препинания. Запятые тут нужны или тире?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Специально для вас ― чтобы слегка разбавить текст ― лучшая подборка из передачи.

Придаточное предложение лучше обособить с помощью тире в качестве вставочной конструкции, так как и без вставки здесь желательно сделать паузу и поставить тире.

Сравнить: Специально для вас ―  лучшая подборка из передачи.